# How to view the hibernate subselect query using log4j?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, logging, log4j

I am using `persistence-api-1.0` and `hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA`. I have a class `Car` defined as follows:

```
@Entity(name = "CarEntity")
@Table(name = "CAR")
@NamedQuery(name = CarEntity.Queries.BY_IDS.NAME, query = CarEntity.Queries.BY_IDS.TEXT)

 public class CarEntity
    {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "CAR_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
      private long carId;

      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "car", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
      private Collection<CarComponentEntity> components= new ArrayList<CarComponentEntity>();  

      public Collection<CarComponentEntity> getComponents()
      {
        return components;
      }

        public static interface Queries
       {
         interface BY_IDS
         {
            String NAME = "CarEntity.ByIDs";
            String TEXT = "select component from CarEntity component where component.id in (:ids)";
            String PARAMETER_CAR_IDS = "ids";
         }
       }
    }
```

I am unable to view the subselect query above. Here is what I have specified in my `log4j.properties`:

```
 log4j.rootLogger = WARN, standard  
    log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG  
    log4j.logger.org.hibernate.trace=TRACE  
    log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type = TRACE
```

My question is how does the `Collection` of `CarComponentEntity` get populated when the query to fetch `CarEntity` is constructed, since `CarComponent` isn't a column on `Car` but vice-versa is true? More importantly how do I view that query?

Additionally, I am not using Spring or hibernate xml file.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the log4j showing the sql statements?

Comment: @Sandhu - No, it only shows the SQL showing selection from the Car table and since CarComponent isn't a part of the Car table I don't see it.